# Increase data transfer out on azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is it possible to increase the data transfer out on Azure?
I am currently using 1383.203% of 5 GB and the red bar looks rather ominous

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a programming question; it's an account management question, one that is probably answered with a credit card to go beyond what Windows Azure is giving you for free (likely Web Sites since you referenced the 5GB bandwidth limit).

Comment: I did have the trial initially but have since gone 'live' and I am a paying customer now. I can remember setting the limit when started but presumed I could change it after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5GB '[limit](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/)' is just what you get for free:

*We are running a promotion through June 30, 2013 where the first 5 GB of data transfers used per month is at no charge.*

By default Windows Azure uses [Pay-as-you-go](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/purchase-options/), you can transfer how much you like in egress traffic and you'll simply pay a fixed price for each GB exceeding the 5 GB free data (per month).

Comment: OK. I am a paying customer so will it just charge beyond the free 5GB ? It does have a price of how much, but surely there should be a way to say "OK I know I will be over hitting the 5GB, lets increase this accordingly so everything looks neat and tidy' ?